# Abbreviation for partial key

Tags: database, database-design

i am preparing a database schema diagram and couldn't find an abbreviation for partial key. Is there an abbreviation for partial key like FK or PK ? How can i indicate that it is a partial key?

Comment: Are you talking about one component of a composite key?

Comment: I am talking about the discriminator of the weak entity, i think we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about making an ER diagram, and including a weak entity, then the following diagram illustrates how to display a partial key. The attribute Line Item Number is a partial key, and it has a dashed underline under it.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Weak_entity_ER-example.svg

If, on the other hand, you are talking about a relational schema diagram,  then it's different.